# Measuring mass of an object in outer space

Tags: experimental-physics, technology

How do (or will) people measure the masses of objects in outer space? (Like in ISS).

Comment: Although this question has already been answered, it's important to point out that the ISS is NOT deep space without gravitation. Infact the gravity at the ISS only falls by 10%. The reason astronauts feel weightless is due to the absence of contact forces, and the reason everything floats is because due to the nature of the gravitational force, the acceleration and orbital velocity of every object is identical (regardless of the mass) so there is no relative motion

Comment: Go to the source:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oU3pp_4n84U

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply a known force to the object, measure its acceleration, then use $m = \frac F a$ to find its mass.

Or swing the object in a circle with radius $r$ at constant speed $v$, measure the centripetal force, use $m = \frac {Fr}{v^2}$ to find its mass.

Or hit the object with a known mass $M$ travelling at relative speed $u$, measure the velocities $v_M$ and $v_m$ after the collision, and then by conservation of momentum $m = M\frac{u - v_M}{v_m}$.

Edit:
A calibrated [spring scale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spring_scale) (a.k.a. a newton meter) lets you apply a known force or measure an unknown force.